# Extracting variables from gridded netcdf data into ASCII

Tags: python-2.7, ascii, netcdf

I would like to know if anyone has any experience extracting information from gridded climate data and organizing it in a way that would be easier to work with to produce a time series. I am not sure how to use the indices (`i` and `j` or `lat` and `lon`, respectively) and I would like to only select data from above 60 degrees latitude.  When I tried to extract the data to line it up I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError: slicing expression exceeds the number of dimensions of the variable"

I am trying to put the data in the following table format:

```
Date,  lat,    lon,    snc
```

The header information is:

```
netcdf snc_day_MPI-ESM-LR_amip_r1i1p1_19790101-20081231 {
dimensions:
    time = UNLIMITED ; // (10958 currently)
    lat = 96 ;
    lon = 192 ;
    bnds = 2 ;
variables:
    double time(time) ;
        time:bounds = "time_bnds" ;
        time:units = "days since 1979-1-1 00:00:00" ;
        time:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
        time:axis = "T" ;
        time:long_name = "time" ;
        time:standard_name = "time" ;
    double time_bnds(time, bnds) ;
    double lat(lat) ;
        lat:bounds = "lat_bnds" ;
        lat:units = "degrees_north" ;
        lat:axis = "Y" ;
        lat:long_name = "latitude" ;
        lat:standard_name = "latitude" ;
    double lat_bnds(lat, bnds) ;
    double lon(lon) ;
        lon:bounds = "lon_bnds" ;
        lon:units = "degrees_east" ;
        lon:axis = "X" ;
        lon:long_name = "longitude" ;
        lon:standard_name = "longitude" ;
    double lon_bnds(lon, bnds) ;
    float snc(time, lat, lon) ;
        snc:standard_name = "surface_snow_area_fraction" ;
        snc:long_name = "Snow Area Fraction" ;
        snc:units = "%" ;
        snc:cell_methods = "time: mean" ;
        snc:cell_measures = "area: areacella" ;
        snc:history = "2011-05-26T14:06:06Z altered by CMOR: replaced missing value flag (1e+22) with standard missing value (1e+20)." ;
        snc:missing_value = 1.e+20f ;
        snc:_FillValue = 1.e+20f ;
        snc:associated_files = "baseURL: http://cmip-pcmdi.llnl.gov/CMIP5/dataLocation gridspecFile: gridspec_landIce_fx_MPI-ESM-LR_amip_r0i0p0.nc areacella: areacella_fx_MPI-ESM-LR_amip_r0i0p0.nc" ;

// global attributes:
        :institution = "Max Planck Institute for Meteorology" ;
        :institute_id = "MPI-M" ;
        :experiment_id = "amip" ;
        :source = "MPI-ESM-LR 2011; URL: http://svn.zmaw.de/svn/cosmos/branches/releases/mpi-esm-cmip5/src/mod; atmosphere: ECHAM6 (REV: 4418), T63L47; land: JSBACH (REV: 4418);" ;
        :model_id = "MPI-ESM-LR" ;
        :forcing = "GHG Oz SD Sl Vl LU" ;
        :parent_experiment_id = "N/A" ;
        :parent_experiment_rip = "N/A" ;
        :branch_time = 0. ;
        :contact = "cmip5-mpi-esm@dkrz.de" ;
        :history = "Model raw output postprocessing with modelling environment (IMDI) at DKRZ: URL: http://svn-mad.zmaw.de/svn/mad/Model/IMDI/trunk, REV: 3135 2011-05-26T14:06:06Z CMOR rewrote data to comply with CF standards and CMIP5 requirements." ;
        :references = "ECHAM6: n/a; JSBACH: Raddatz et al., 2007. Will the tropical land biosphere dominate the climate-carbon cycle feedback during the twenty first century? Climate Dynamics, 29, 565-574, doi 10.1007/s00382-007-0247-8;" ;
        :initialization_method = 1 ;
        :physics_version = 1 ;
        :tracking_id = "7c36f2e9-7f1a-4bcc-94f5-bf2ab21dd16d" ;
        :product = "output" ;
        :experiment = "AMIP" ;
        :frequency = "day" ;
        :creation_date = "2011-05-26T14:06:06Z" ;
        :Conventions = "CF-1.4" ;
        :project_id = "CMIP5" ;
        :table_id = "Table day (27 April 2011) 86d1558d99b6ed1e7a886ab3fd717b58" ;
        :title = "MPI-ESM-LR model output prepared for CMIP5 AMIP" ;
        :parent_experiment = "N/A" ;
        :modeling_realm = "landIce land" ;
        :realization = 1 ;
        :cmor_version = "2.5.9" ;
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you want snc as a dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I guess this is the problem is that I am trying to figure out how to arrange the data where I can just use the snc information to produce a time series for one particular area shown with lat and lon.  There is no station id or indexing information so how would I arrange this information from gridded data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with N1B4 on use of ncks. Also note that ncks accepts coordinate *values* (indicated by decimal points) not just indices  (indicated by indices). Hence, e.g., latitude values greater than 60 degrees can be obtained by

```
ncks -d lat,60., in.nc
```

without knowing the underlying coordinate grid exactly.

Comment: Thank you very much! From yours and the above help it has led me to find out all the great (and efficient) ways I can use NCO for my netCDF data.  However, due to the large amount of data from these files, as well as missing data, is there a way I can omit the data that has missing values so that the output only selects data where applicable? I don't know if this is something I should open a new question for. Thank you again!

Comment: There is no elegant way to omit the missing values. However, if space is your concern, then output the file as netCDF4 format with compression and you may greatly reduce the output filesize. E.g., try ncks -4 -L 1 -d lat,60., in.nc out.nc

Comment: Oops, I see you want ASCII output, so netCDF4 is not helpful. Instead pipe the output of ncks into a UNIXy filter that removes lines containing the missing value. Such a filter can be written in Perl, awk, etc. Since missing values are printed as an underscore by default, it may work simply to echo all lines that do not contain an underscore, e.g., ncks -d lat,60., in.nc | awk my_script

Answer (score 1):

`ncks` from the NCO package is ideal for this type of procedure.  You can easily extract a time series of snc for latitudes greater than 60 degrees.  You need to first identify the indices in the dimension `lat` that contain values greater than 60.

```
ncks -v lat infile.nc | more
```

This will print the values of `lat` (the variable, not the dimension).  Without having the file, let's just say values greater than 60 are 80-96.  Remember that in Python (and NCO), the first index is 0, so the range of 80-96 is 79-95 in zero-index world.

Now we can use `ncks` to extract values of snc within the `lat` range of 79-95.

```
ncks -v snc -d lat,79,95 infile.nc -O outfile.nc
```

You can add as many dimension slices as you want using ncks.  If you want a specific `time` and `lon` range, simply add it on! For example,

```
ncks -v snc -d lat,79,95 -d lon,0,25 -d time,0,5 infile.nc -O outfile.nc
```

Comment: I see that it is doing a great job selecting the correct ranges. I think this may be exactly what I need but I will need to spend some time with it or look further into the nco discussion forums perhaps. Thank you very much for your input and for introducing the user-friendly nco option.